# Replaceing normal function (event) to arrow function causes issue

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Hello I see that similar questions have showed up before.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttf3CEsEwMQ). In this tutorial he prevents the default submit button tutorial by using

```
function addTodo (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

I wish to convert this to a arrow function. I have tried this:

```
let addTodo = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Then I get a error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration

Comment: Why are you using let. Use const.

Comment: I believe the error is not referring to your arrow syntax. When are you calling addTodo()? Could you share some more code to understand the context this function is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the full error message is [ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration`X' before initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init).

Function declarations are hoisted.

Assignments to variables are not.

You can't read `addTodo` before you assign a value to it.

Change the order of your source code.

Comment: Thanks! If I would like to divide the code into three sections.

1. Definitions of HTML GUI (document.querySelector)
2. Eventlistning from HTML GUI
3. Functions

Can I in some creative way solve this?

Comment: You don't need a creative way. You just need to put the three things in the right order.

Comment: I understand that setting the right order works. Could I set a placeholder value to the function and then redeclare it later?

Comment: No, that isn't something JS supports.

Answer (score -1):

Does using 'const' instead of 'let' solve the problem?

```
const addTodo = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```